# Multiply value of two divs and then replace one with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento

I want to do an A/B test in the future. For that, I changed the cart a little bit in Magento. My code for that is:

```
<ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list clearer">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="product-details">
      <p class="product-name">Product #1</p>
      <strong>6</strong><br/>
      <span class="price">9,14&nbsp;€</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="product-details">
      <p class="product-name">Product #2</p>
      <strong>3</strong><br/>
      <span class="price">7,36&nbsp;€</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="product-details">
      <p class="product-name">Product #3</p>
      <strong>3</strong><br/>
      <span class="price">7,36&nbsp;€</span>
    </div>
  </li> 
</ol>
```

In each "item" I want to multiply the value in the `<strong>` tag with the price since its only for the amount of one. Then I want to replace whats standing in `<span class="price">` with the real costs of the product.

A way to multiply it could be

```
var one = parseInt($(".itemOne").text(), 10);
var two = parseInt($(".itemTwo").text(), 10);
$(".total").text(one * two);
```

but I don't know how to replace the value and how to get rid of the `&nbsp;` and €. Maybe you guys have an idea?!

Comment: use data attribute to store price in span tag and get that value

Comment: `$(".price").each(function() {
  var val = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",",".")); console.log(val);
})` without changing anything. I would not use the textual representation of the values though but do what Parth suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  var cost = (parseFloat($(this).find('span.price').text().replace(',','.')) * parseInt($(this).find('strong').text())).toFixed(2);
  
  $(this).find('span.price').text(cost + ' €');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list clearer">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="product-details">
      <p class="product-name">Product #1</p>
      <strong>6</strong><br/>
      <span class="price">9,14&nbsp;€</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="product-details">
      <p class="product-name">Product #2</p>
      <strong>3</strong><br/>
      <span class="price">7,36&nbsp;€</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="product-details">
      <p class="product-name">Product #3</p>
      <strong>3</strong><br/>
      <span class="price">7,36&nbsp;€</span>
    </div>
  </li> 
</ol>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Well awesome I didn't thought that it was that easy and I understand what you are doing AND it works :) thanks a lot

Comment: @Kesaja Welcome buddy :)